# LINQ Simple Query takes over 30s

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a problem with a very simple query using EF.
The following query takes over 30s to run and throws a timeout error:

```
var results = _Context.Entity
            .Where(x => list1.Contains(x.Id))
            .Where(x => !list2.Contains(x.Id))
            .ToList();
```

While the one below runs in a 1/4 of a second:

```
var results = _Context.Entity
            .Where(x => list1.Contains(x.Id))
            .ToList();

results = results
            .Where(x => !list2.Contains(x.Id))
            .ToList();
```

The collection in the db is about 60k rows, and both my Lists are about 5k int.
Is it a caching issue? I have many similar queries in my app that all run smoothly. What could I do to improve it?

Comment: Once you do .ToList() the query is translated to sql and executed in the database, therefore the second query you shared does two round trips to db with a possibly more simple sql query. You could try following a similar approach in the first one as well.

Comment: If your lists are 5k long, then you are sending 5k variables to the server. I'm not even sure how that works at all.

Comment: Sending 5K of parameters to what would be the functional equivalent of a sql IN statement would definitely cause performance issues. Where are the values for `list1` and `list2` originating from? Is this the result of a previous Db filter operation? If so it would be more efficient to use joins or a more "complex" query that would resulted in less I/O.

Comment: First scenario is slow because the query is trying to filter two different lists at the same time, and it
checks every records in 60k records twice,  that impacts the performance. So either a record match or not it stills 
check that till it reaches last record. 

However, second scenario is working differently because first list will return 5k records out of 60k so it will 
will check 5k against list2 record only  instead of  60k.

Comment: They are coming from a UI widget, where I am only getting Ids back. In prod it likely will not be that big (<100) but I was testing the worst case scenario. I changed my code to run on a queried subset of the collection, rather than on the context directly.

Answer (score 1):

In case 1 you build a more complex query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Entities WHERE Id in (...) AND Id NOT IN (...)
```

But in case 2 you make a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM Entities WHERE Id in (...)
```

and then filter out the results in C#. It would work even faster if your `list2` was actually a `HashSet`. However, you make SQL server return redundant rows which will be filtered out.

I guess, the first one works slower, because it doesn't utilize index, but I am not sure, I may be wrong.

What is more important, what you actually want is to get all items where ID is in `list1`, but not in `list2`. In this case, you don't need to make SQL server handle it - just filter out it in code and then pass only those IDs which you need:

```
var listToSearch = list1.Except(list2).ToArray();
var results = _Context.Entity.Where(x => listToSearch.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first one is checking running the sql which to where conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE id IN () AND id NOT IN ()
```

Where as the second is only running the check where in query:

```
SELECT * FROM Entity WHERE id IN ()
```

The where check on the second statement of the second one:

```
results = results
        .Where(x => !list2.Contains(x.Id))
        .ToList();
```

Is actually getting ran on the webserver and not using sql. As soon as you type .ToList() you execute the SQL Linq.

Anyway the reason the first is slower than the second is because it's comparing every element in Entity to both lists. Where as the second checks to see if the id is in the list and then returns a list of items which meet that criteria. Then the program is using the returned filtered list (most likely fewer rows than the total some of your entity table) to check to make sure that list doesn't contain a row with the id from list 2 in it.

So the second just has fewer comparisons going on.